# How to transfer user data, namely tracks and favorite places, from OsmAnd to OsmAnd+ application?

Tags: data-transfer, osmand

I used to use OsmAnd application, and while using it have created a few favorite places, and recorded a few tracks.

Now that I switched to OsmAnd Plus, I'd like to copy all user-created data, like favorites and tracks, from OsmAnd to OsmAnd Plus, and then delete OsmAnd to save space.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried to export the data and then import? `Menu → Configure profile → Actions` https://osmand.net/docs/user/personal/import-export/

Comment: Thanks, that worked, though I had to save the exported file (via Google Drive), and then open it... exporting to OsmAnd+ directly via share menu somehow didn't work.